# Simple Mod_rewrite rule for a simple website (Classic) :(

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I have been making my own little website with a small CMS. And i just can't get mod_rewrite to work for me, what i'm after seems simple and straightforward.
Right now my links look like this:
localhost/cms/?page=history,
localhost/cms/?news=galery-module
etc..
I want them to look like this: 
localhost/cms/page/history

The code in my .htacess file right now is(but it does not seem to work although MOD_rewrite is on):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /cms1/([-A-z0-9]+) /cms1/?page=$1
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule /cms1/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /cms1/?$1=$2
```

Also note that I wrote `cms1` and not `cms`, it was in your rules but not in your urls, adjust accordingly.